# How to change Microsoft Office Language?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office, language

I have Legal license of Microsoft Office 2010 and Legal license of Windows 8.

The OS, Windows 8 is English and the Microsoft Office is Hebrew. It's very uncomfortable, because Hebrew is a Right-To-Left language while English is a Left-To-Right.

Anyway, How to change the Office language to English? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Windows and office keys are not language dependent, so just uninstall the hebrew version of office and install an english version with the same key.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/language-packs/localized-versions-of-office-suites-FX102901428.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Buy the Office 2010 MUI pack:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-US/language-packs/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I am not familiar with Windows 8. I can only describe this from a Windows 7 perspective, e.g, Start menu.

Check to see that you have the Language Settings tool installed along with Office. From the Start menu > Microsoft Office > Microsoft Office .... Tools. If you did not find it then make sure it is installed. Control Panel > Programs and Features. Find Office in the list of programs. Do not click on it but right-click on it and choose Change. Navigate through the list of available features, Tools, and see if Language Tools is an option for you.

My Language Settings allows me to add many "editing languages". This may not be what you're looking for. If you do find it, add another "editing language", then your Office programs may still be in Hebrew but editing/document may allow for the other language.

Good luck.

Comment: @user1798362 It would have done that in Windows 7 too..